# When should I use an object database?

Tags: database, web-applications, architecture, relational-database, object-oriented-database

I have been using relational databases for some time now and recently came across a different type of database: object database. One of the products built around this idea had a description: A scalable, "post-relational" database with a multidimensional data and application server for distributed web applications.

This makes me wonder, when am I supposed to use such a database? I mean, Facebook must be using MySQL and it seems to be doing fine and it can be considered a large-scale distributed web application. The same goes for some other web applications such as Twitter and Orkut perhaps. Given that this is the case, when am I supposed to use an Object database?

Comment: Twitter dropped MySQL for Cassandra http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/407159447/cassandra-twitter-an-interview-with-ryan-king (can't really answer your question though)

Comment: And Facebook is actually the original developer of [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra).

Comment: @Olivier Twitter is **still** using MySQL for the tweets, they use Cassandra for a some internal things only. See the official [clarification](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/07/cassandra-at-twitter-today.html) @Matthew And Facebook is rumored to have dropped Cassandra completely. See [this post](http://www.ora600.be/news/i%E2%80%99m-collecting-data-points-nosql-and-hvsp-adoption). And at the end, both Twitter and Facebook are still using MySQL.

Comment: Well Facebook uses MySQL mainly as a key-value-store and doesn't do to much complex operations or joins. Source: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Scale-at-Facebook

Answer (score 3):

Object databases work really well when you have deep object graphs (e.g., CAD or finite element models with lots of geometric entities).  Doing all those JOINs in a relational database would be prohibitively expensive, but it's natural for an object database.